# Java: How to restrict writing data to a single line

Tags: java, cryptography, biginteger

I have 2 `BigIntegers` as

```
BigInteger p = new BigInteger(bits, certainty, new SecureRandom());
BigInteger q = new BigInteger(bits, certainty, new SecureRandom());
```

I convert them into byte array and write them in a file as

```
private static void write(String file, BigInteger... values) throws IOException {
    try (FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
        for (BigInteger b : values) {
            fileStream.write(b.toByteArray());
            fileStream.write(new byte[]{(byte) '\n'});
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I open the file, the result spawns more than 2 lines. I need to write them one per line so that later I can fetch them.

I call the function as:

```
write("public", p, q);
```

The result is binary and varies the number of lines it writes. So sometimes, it is 2 or 3 or even 6!

Is there a way this can be achieved? Or is there any other workaround?

Comment: I'm confused, is this not working because it is 3 lines instead of 2?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I need 2 lines of data so that I can fetch it later

Comment: could you maybe include the file in your post and also include how you used the method `write`?

Comment: this cannot be accomplished reliably, as the character \n could also be interpreted as a byte from your BigInteger

Comment: @ControlAltDel, what do you suggest in this case??

Comment: Don't write binary if line breaks matter to you.  Maybe base 64 would be a good option for you?  Hard to tell when you haven't really stated your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work reliably the way you are trying to do it (see my comment)

If you want 1 BigInteger per line, you've got to write it out in text

```
PrintWriter pw = ...;

for (BigInteger b : values) {
  pw.println(b.toString());
}
```

Comment: @user7201762 yes of course its possible... You can use encryption. But one problem at a time.

Comment: Base 64 as David suggested would be *less* readable and shorter as well. But three-fingered-salute is right when he says that encryption is the only way to make it unreadable. That's indeed a different problem though.

Answer (score -1):

You're writing out a new line after every value in your loop. I think you're seeing one extra line because you write a new line out every time.

Comment: I open the file using notepad++. There I can clearly see there are more than 2 lines because there are line numbers

Comment: OK, certain values will contain bytes that are new line characters will create your multiple lines, i.e. 680202. So you will be stuck if you want to write out the straight bytes. You could put a start/stop indicator, like 10 pound signs or encrypt the string value as ControlAltDel suggested.